# Azure AD SSO to Facebook if user is already logged in

Tags: azure, entra-id, single-sign-on, azure-web-apps

Hi

I'm in the IT dept. for a small charity.

We use Facebook as a way to promote events to the local community. Our (few) volunteers have accounts in our 365, and use this to log in to everything.

We have set up AzureAD password-based SSO to normal Facebook login, and this works fine with the azure secure-sign-on extension--EXCEPT if a user is already logged in. Then, the login page URL redirects to the user's personal facebook page.

My question:  Is there a way to make sure the user is logged in with SSO, not taken to their personal account. (by forcing existing user to logout, or bypassing the redirect to the users account)

This could only be done with a single URL...

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I'm sure you're aware already, this is due to session cookies from the previous sign in. Without the removal of those session cookies, there is not much that you can do mechanically.

If you are using chrome, you can have people set up Chrome Profiles, setting up for one work and one for personal. This would keep sessions unique and allow people to navigate their personal facebook and their work facebook in different windows. You would need to emphazie that people pay attention to what they post so it's not accidentally the org instead of the person. This is the simplest way to have session separation.

https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/2364824?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en

https://www.howtogeek.com/255653/how-to-find-your-chrome-profile-folder-on-windows-mac-and-linux/

Cheers!